# Set minimum Adobe Reader version for PDF file in meta data

Tags: metadata, adobe

**How to set a minimum version of the Adobe Reader to open a PDF file?**

There is a property like this:

[image: PDF Properties]

The highlighted texts says: "**Can be opened with: All Acrobat-Versions**"

So how to change this in meta data?

And is there a chance to force the OS to open the file with Adobe Reader if it is available? Otherwise there is a big chance that my 3D data models can't be opened from the user. Thanks!

Comment: imho the entry is only relevant for the safety setting (if you set a password, the encryption method must be compatible), it is not content related. And you can force a user OS to use a specific application (as a user I wouldn't like this at all anyway). Write a warning at the begin of the pdf.

Comment: The "can be opened by" field in Adobe Reader is displaying the version of the PDF specification that the document claims to conform to. PDF version 1.7 requires at least Adobe Reader version 8, PDF version 1.6 requires at least Adobe Reader version 7, etc. You can change the PDF version for content created by pdftex or luatex using `\pdfminorversion=7` for example, but should only do this if the content really conforms to that version of the PDF specification. If your 3D content requires features from the PDF 2.0 specification, I believe that pdftex and luatex can't generate that.

Comment: @EricMarsden. I'm not sure if it is connected to the version. I did set it 2.0 (luatex can do it) and the entry didn't change.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer indeed, I was mistaking this for the PDF version shown in the first tab in this "document properties" window. Like you say, this is perhaps related to the higher quality encryption settings available in more recent PDF versions.